# Generics in Java during inheritence

Tags: java, generics

I have a

```
public class Person {
    public Person() {
        super();
    }
}
public class Employee extends Person {
    public Employee() {
       super();
    }
}
```

From a different java file:

```
public <T extends Person> T gPerson(){
    Employee p = new Employee();
    return p;
}

public Person getPerson(){
    Employee p = new Employee();
    return p;
}
```

First method gPerson() has a compile time error: Cannot convert from Employee to T. Why is this error.

Comment: Because you don't know what T will be.

Comment: The return type of `gPerson` simply makes no sense. It should be simply Employee.

Answer (score 3):

```
public <T extends Person> T gPerson()
```

means that `gPerson` returns some unknown type that must be either Person or a sub-class of Person.

This means that :

```
NonEmployee ne = gPerson();
```

is legal (assuming `NonEmployee` is some class that extends `Person`).
Therefore `gPerson` can't return an `Employee`, since `Employee` can't be cast to `NonEmployee`).

Comment: All right. Since NonEmployee cannot be cast to Employee, hence the function gPerson() cannot return Employee. So what type of object can this function return. As you say: gPerson returns some unknown type that must be either Person or a sub-class of Person, is Employee not a sub-class of Person? (Employee extends Person)

Comment: @user1001254 Actually, I don't think it can return anything other than `null`.

Comment: @user1001254 Employee is a sub-class of Person, but the caller of the method can assign the result of the method to a variable that is not Employee, and therefore cannot be assigned an Employee instance.